# Vue.js body of post method is always empty

Tags: javascript, spring, vue.js

I want to send `POST` method to `localhost` which some content in `body` part. My code from `vue` file is:

```
methods: {
      login(){
          var data = {
              username: 'admin',
              password: 'admin'
          }
        this.$http.post("http://localhost:8081/login", data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
      }
    }
```

I use Spring-boot as server and have breakpoint in `attemptAuthentication` method from implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class. For check `body` I use:

```
String myBody= httpServletRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

but this `String` is always empty(breakpoint works). I tried put some value manually to `post` method like:

```
this.$http.post("http://localhost:8081/login", "exampleData")
```

but value is still empty.

When I send the same method from Postman - it works very well - `myBody` contains correct value.

What is wrong with my code?

@Update

1) for raw and json I configured Postman:

[image]
in my java class is:

```
myBody = {"username":"admin","password":"admin"}
myContentType = application/json
```

2) For form:
[image]

java classes looks like:

```
myBody = 
------WebKitFormBoundarykeEtHWmW4BBv2y0t
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

admin
------WebKitFormBoundarykeEtHWmW4BBv2y0t
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

admin
------WebKitFormBoundarykeEtHWmW4BBv2y0t--
```

@Update

I added header for my `post` method:

```
methods: {
      login(){
        this.$http.post("http://localhost:8081/login", "exampleData", {
          headers: {
            'content-type' : 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
      }
    }
```

but in java class `myBody` is empty and `content-type` is `null`. There are no errors in console(in browse)

Answer (score 0):

You should check your server is get the request's `body` or `form`?

like so:

[image]

check brower params like so:

[image]

Comment: If you use the `form-data` to transmit data, you should ensure the brower's post request's content-type = `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8`

Comment: My solution is use the `application/json` type.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is normal for brower.

`application/form-data` is old used for file upload.

`application/json` is flexible and generic.

Comment: i edited post again and put there my current vue.js code

Comment: im pretty sure that problem is because `content-type` is invalid (is not json) but have no idea how to solve it

Comment: Are you useing vue-resource？

Comment: [look this](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/config.md#legacy-web-servers)

Comment: yes, Im using vue-resource and i tried `emulateJson/emulateHttp` but still nothing (probably this is not problem - from Postman i send as `application/json` and it works)